# How to dismiss bootstrap modal on click in ui grid angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-grid

In my angular app coded in typescript, I am using **ui grid** to display some data in a **bootstrap modal**. What I want to achieve is that on click on any of the columns in a grid row modal closes. How can I make it happen? I am not using **$modal** or **$modalInstance** now, there is no need for this since it is a SPA. Is there a way to not use them and call modal.dismiss() **onRowSelection**?

Comment: I have an SPA (as in single page application?) using $modal and $modalInstance, I don't think they are related that way. Do you have any code to show us? a plunker maybe?

Comment: There is nothing related between $modal and $modalInstance and having a SPA application. If you want to interact with the modal use the $modalInstance

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to open modal.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    template: require('./modal.html'),
    controller: require('./search.controller'),
    controllerAs: 'searchModalInstance',
    scope: $scope,
    size: 'lg',
    windowClass: 'search-modal-popup'
  });
```

After that, add modalInstance scope into ui-grid appScopeProvider [UI-Grid GridOptions](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions)

like, `uiGridOption.appScopeProvider = modalInstance;`

Now, you can close modal by calling function `close()` from ui-grid.

Comment: Is there any way to close modal without having to use this open function? This part is really unnecessary piece of code for my app.

Comment: @cAMPy Then you can use $modaStack.getTop().key.close() to close modal.

$modalStack.getTop() returns current opened modal object.

Comment: Amit unfortunately this does not work. I get en error:
Error: _this.$modalStack.getTop(...) is undefined. I added my modal to uiGridOptions:

                appScopeProvider: document.getElementById("idOftheDivWhichClassIsModalFade"),

Comment: @cAMPy, Please add dependency `$modalStack` on your controller.

Please share plunker code.

Comment: I do have this dependency injected. My code is written in typescript which as far as I know is not supported by plunker :(